# php- How do I match value of two arrays with the same index only?

Tags: php, arrays

So I have

```
array1= ['a','b','c']
array2= ['b','a','c']
```

And I want it to return ' c' only

I want to match value of  array1[0] with value of arrray2[0] and if it doesn't match, move on to the next index

I tried array_intersect, but it keeps going through the arrays until theres a match.  So not what I'm looking for.

Comment: foreach loops and check each index

Comment: please specific your question, are you trying find same index value from arrays?

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: My expected output is c

Comment: So you missed [array_intersect_assoc()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect-assoc.php) when you were reading the PHP Docs

Comment: lol I guess I did. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
$array1= ['a','b','c'];
$array2= ['b','a','c'];
foreach($array1 as $key=>$value){
    if($value==$array2[$key]){
     echo 'match value' .$value;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Why do it with a loop like this when there's a built-in function designed to eliminate the need for coding it yourself?